# Fix security vulnerability in dnsmasq on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, apt, dnsmasq

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server using dnsmasq and recently ran into the following security vulnerability which does not seem to have a fix on 12.04.
http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2012/CVE-2012-3411.html
How do I go about fixing this issue?  Should I uninstall dnsmasq/libvirt and try to install their .deb's from 13.04?

Comment: You could try installing the 13.04 dnsmasq binaries.  If that doesn't work, they you may have to backport dnsmasq yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debating trying the binaries from 13.04 I decided I will just forego the ease of setup and lightweightedness that dnsmasq had allotted me and switch to bind9.  Problem solved.  Probably switch back to dnsmasq whenever getting around to upgrading this server to 13.04 or next LTS.

Zoredache, thanks for the suggestions.